# Java returning Array Out Of Bounds Exception

Tags: java, arrays

I have some code which compares integers in a array to a given value, and creates a new array with values that are higher then the given value only. This is my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class ex6{
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] a = {12, 13, 14};
    filter(a, 15);
}

public static int[] filter(int[] a, int b){
    int[] newArray = {};
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        if(a[i] < b){
            newArray[i] = a[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
    return newArray;
    }
}
```

However, when I try to run my code, it returns a Array Out Of Bounds Exception which I cant figure out why. The Loop only runs through the length of the Array so this shouldn't be this happening.

Comment: Maybe use a debugger to check the size of the array `newArray`. It probably isn't what you think it is.

Comment: *Hint:* Java arrays are fixed size. You cannot add elements to an empty array.

Comment: *"creates a new array with values that are **higher** than the given value"* Then why is your code trying to assign values that are **lower** than `b` to the new array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because your new array is empty.

```
int[] newArray = {};
```

Try to set it to the size which equals to array `a`:

```
int[] newArray = new int[a.length];
```

Comment: Depends on the requirements which are not mentioned.

Comment: @Lothar It's "mentioned" through OP's code. Method filter returns a new array with elements < b. So the worst case is all elements being lesser than b, which returns an identical array of the same size.

Comment: Let's wait on a reaction of the OP - if there is any. Since the code is wrong the way it is, it's hard to say, what the original intention of this code-equivalence of "do what I mean" was.

Comment: Sure, but this one looks like a question from the school which I doubt they are allowed to use stream.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem with school assignments. They were created 10 years ago and don't you dare solve things with stuff that was added since then and that should help you avoid the very mistakes we see here...

Answer (score 0):

`newArray` is of length `0` so as soon as `a` is non-empty, `newArray[i]` will lead to the exception you see.

Maybe what you actually want is the following:

```
public static int[] filter(int[] a, int b){
    return Arrays.stream(a)
        .filter(elem -> elem < b)
        .toArray();
}
```

This differs from user3437460's answer that the result of this is an array that only contains elements that fit the condition while user3437460's result is an array with the same size as the original one but all elements that are below a threshold are replaced by `0`. Which one is correct depends on the requirements that you haven't pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a `newArray` with exactly 0 elements in it, and then you try to set elements in it beyond its allocated element slots.

You have to know the array size upfront in order to allocate the right amount. The way you have structured your code you could do that with `newArray = new int[a.length]`. That would, in this case work because if your filter condition matches you assign the value at exactly the same index as in the original array `newArray[i] = a[i]`. The skipped values will remain the value '0', which you may or may not want.

This might be what you want, but in general programmers *don't use arrays* in their programs, they use the different classes from the collections library, such as lists and sets. Having an array of ints is very unlikely in modern programming.

Since Java 8 this kind of problem would preferably be solved by a stream, filtering in the wanted elements and them collecting them into a list, or maybe into a array. In case of primitive ints probably a collection:

```
public static int[] filter(int[] a, int b) { 
    return Arrays.stream(a)  // creates an IntStream
           .filter(v -> v < b) // filter in the elements where the v < b
           .toArray(); // collect them into an array
}
```

I want to repeat my warning that if you need this type of code you are *probably* designing it the wrong way. Very much *probably*.

If you really, really, really, want to do it via an array, and want to return a downsized array you need to allocate an array with the biggest size needed (a.length), keep the index of where to insert in the `newArray` and at the end create yet another array holding the amount of filtered entries, and then use [`System.arraycopy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) to copy those elements into your array.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the `newArray` to an empty one:

```
int[] newArray = {};
```

Then you are trying to assign the element at index *i* a value, while the array has no element:

```
newArray[i] = a[i];
```

You should initialize the array with an appropriate size in order to be able to assign / read values for its elements. This may be the argument `a` array length by default but could be optimized depending on your needs:

```
class ex6 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] a = {12, 13, 14};
        filter(a, 15);
    }

    public static int[] filter(int[] a, int b){
        int[] newArray = new int[a.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            if(a[i] < b){
                newArray[i] = a[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
        return newArray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you said that the new array must contain the values that are greater than the given value and not less but you are doing the reverse.

Instead of

```
if(a[i] < b)
```

this will come:

```
if(a[i] > b)
```

Plus, if you use ArrayList here, it could help you reduce the space occupied as in the case of creating an array you will have to initialize the array size.

So, your algorithm will look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] a = {12, 13, 14,16};
    filter(a, 15);
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> filter(int[] a, int b){
    ArrayList<Integer> newArray = new ArrayList<>(); //dynamically increases as per the requirement
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        if(a[i] > b){   // Higher values, not lower
            newArray.add(a[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray.toArray()));
    return newArray;
}
```